# CSS margin problem

Tags: css, html

I am new to CSS, so please bear with me. I have this form which I'm trying to style. Everything works fine, except the confirmation label which is in a div. I want some space to be there between div.field, and while this works for all the input elements, it doesn't work for the label message which is at the bottom. I tried increasing margin-top, but to no avail. I would like that element to be positioned in the center.

Using the web-developer addon of Firefox, it shows me that the width and height of div.field of label tag specifically is 284px and 209px respectively. Why is this so, when I haven't set it that way?

You can view the code live at jsfiddle: http://www.jsfiddle.net/yMHJY/

Comment: By the way you have made nice form :)

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question. You want to center the label tag with the ID "label" ("Your Message Has Been Sent")?

Comment: @Soundlink, I want some spacing between the input element "Type 'Yes I am human'" and "Your Message Has Been Sent". If you notice, there's no spacing between them. I tried to add margin-top to the label element, but it made no difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is simple, really. Add a margin-top to the parent of the `label` element, and add `overflow: hidden` to the `div#contact div .field` selector.

---

However, can I just say that the code can be rewritten for much better efficiency and semantic correctness. For instance, I would contain the last massage in a `p` tag and not a `label` in a `div`. Also, I would have each `input` element placed in an unordered list `ul` instead of `div`s. You also have a lot of unnecessary `float`s and the `br` at the end of each `input` is wholly uneeded. Oh, and unless you are embedding Calluna somehow, don't use it - stick to web safe fonts (and if you are, you still need to suggest an alternative, in the user's browser does not support it, and also to give the browser something to display while the font loads).

**Edit**

Fixed the load for ya, I should be paid for this kind of stuff :) Just stick to better HTML and CSS next time.

http://www.jsfiddle.net/SNrtA/

Comment: Thank you! I have never actually read a tutorial on contact forms using lists, it's always mostly the divs. Your solution of adding `overflow:hidden` worked! Thanks for the great pointers as well. Will surely keep that in mind. You were a great help. :)

Answer (score 0):

To center you could add a parent container

```
<div id="parent">
    <label id="label">Your Message Has Been Sent</label>
</div>


div#parent {
 text-align:center;
}
```

or add an id to your original parent div to target it with above css

with regards to the margin, you seem to have an issue with a float:left being set in the

div#contact div input[type=text] class. You need to clear this as it could be causing you margin problems. Try removing this and amending your styles. Why are you floating the inputs left?

Comment: I think they mean vertical center.